# CircleCI - curl Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Tags: config, circleci-2.0

I am getting curl Failed to connect when executing this line of code on config.yml

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  build:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - run: curl http://localhost:8080
```

Where as of `http://google.com` is working fine and returns html any idea why this is happening?